# Given string x,y and z. Determine if z is a shuffle

Tags: algorithm

I am trying this problem:

> Suppose you are given three strings of characters: X, Y, and Z, where |X| = n,  |Y| = m, and |Z| = n+m.Z is said to be a shuffle of X and Y if and only if Z can be formed by interleaving the characters from X and Y in a way that maintains the left-to ­right ordering of the characters from each string.
>
> Give an efficient algorithm that determines whether Z is a shuffle of X and Y.
>
> Hint: the values of the dynamic programming matrix you construct should be Boolean, not numeric

What I don't understand is why everyone is presenting a dynamic programming recursive solution.

Can't we just do the following n+m algo:

1. Maintain two pointers i and j, i points to chars in string x and j for string y.
2. Iterate (with iterator k) through z, for every char z[k] if it match x[i] increment i, if it match y[j] increment j

   2.1. if k > i+j then return false

   2.2. if k == z.length() and  i or j != x.length(), y.length() respectively then return false
3. return `true`

edited according to Tanmay Patil 's post

Comment: You can have backtracking issues, when x [i] == y [j], so you dont know which to consume at a certain point

Comment: perhaps i didnt understand your post, but this is not recursive why would u use backtracking?

Comment: Didnt give it to much thought here, however at some point you iterate through a char 'x' which is currently present in both sttings and it is important to consume the correct one (iterate the correct pointer). Another issue could be, that a dp algorithm is maybe faster.

Comment: Maybe i m just missing a important fact which prevents your algo from doing so

Comment: why is it important to consume the correct one?

Comment: Y=xa  X=xb   Z=xaxb. Iterating j first leads to wrong result no?

Comment: Yes :) it makes sense thank you. The iterative solution is wrong.

Comment: **This** iterative solution is wrong does not mean that it can't be done in an iterative way. Using DP is not compulsory here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem statement clearly says

> Give an efficient dynamic ­programming algorithm

So that should explain

> everyone is presenting a dynamic programming recursive solution

---

Even then, it can be solved in an iterative way as you mentioned. And it is not a n^2 algorithm, it's time complexity is n+m

Good luck.

Comment: The above iterative solution is incorrect. eg. if X = xb , Y = xa, Z = xaxb. Thank you Terry Storm, further discussion in comments of main que.

Comment: This is a classic push down automaton problem, and you need a stack to backtrack. But it can still be done in an iterative way. (Not exactly as you mentioned.)

Answer (score 0):

You're right.

You never, ever **HAVE TO** use recursive algorithms. You're free to do so, but you can **ALWAYS** use an interative routine.

In this example, you could use arrays or allocate a memory block large enough to hold the result.

Comment: My point was, is the algo iv presented above wrong and if not then why go through the hell of DP?